# this.setState does not update the dataSource state after fetch from Firebase in RN

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, state

in the componentDidMount I entered a function that fetch some data from Firebase and can be called each time the user wants to fetch again.

The problem is that the first fetch does not update. After making a then I want to update the array of the dataSource but it doesn't update it. it does update though the loading spinning state.

Here is the Code:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    // DataSource configured
     ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged })

    this.state = { 
        isLoading: true,
        dataSource: ds,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchGroups()     
}
    fetchGroups() {
    firebase.database().ref('groups/numbers').once("value", (snap) => {
        snap.forEach((snapshot) => {
            firebase.database().ref('groups/' + snapshot.val()).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                getparticipant = snapshot.val().participant
            var instantPrice
                switch (true) {
                    case (getparticipant <= 3):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceOne
                        break;
                    case (getparticipant <= 10):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceTwo
                        break;
                    case (getparticipant <= 20):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceThree
                        break;
                    case (getparticipant > 20):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceFourth
                        break;
                }
            dataObject.push({
                title: snapshot.val().type + ' ' + snapshot.val().brand,
                groupId: snapshot.val().groupID,
                description: snapshot.val().model,
                icon: snapshot.val().icon,
                partners: snapshot.val().participant,
                finalDate: snapshot.val().timeMerge,
                space: instantSpace,
                photo: snapshot.val().adminPhoto
                })
            }) 
        })
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(dataObject)
        this.setState({
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(dataObject),
            isLoading: false
        })
        console.log(this.state.isLoading)
        console.log(this.state.dataSource)
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error this.setState is not defined ?

Comment: Im not getting any error. it is just do not update the state. i want to update the listview and i get the right array from firebase. even if i set timeout it will not set the state

Comment: I am only get the first state. and it shows it. (ds) which is: 
      ListViewDataSource {_rowHasChanged: ƒ, _getRowData: ƒ, _sectionHeaderHasChanged: ƒ, _getSectionHeaderData: ƒ, _dataBlob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meet this problem again I searched for professional reason and this is the answer: Objects in JavaScript are pointing to location in memory, other then virabiles who save the value in memory, thus values can be copy to new memory location, however objects don't, they reference to the location of the values in the memory when the object was created. so in order to copy an object Object.assign({}, obj) does the job, or another cleaner solution is to write {...obj}.

Answer (score 3):

`setState` is an [asynchronous operation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Therefore, you won't have its latest value right away.

Should you need to access its latest changes, you can use:

```
this.setState({
  dataSouce: ds.cloneWithRows(dataObject),
  isLoading: false,
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.isLoading)
  console.log(this.state. dataSource)
})
```

```js
const asyncOperation = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      counter: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    
    asyncOperation()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Current state value:', this.state.counter)
        
        this.setState({
          counter: this.state.counter + 1,
          loading: false,
        }, () => {
          console.log('New state value:', this.state.counter)
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click-me
        </button>
        <p>Counter: {this.state.counter}</p>
        {this.state.loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: it does not help to change the state... any other idea?

Comment: @TalTalmon yes. it does. I've updated my answer with an example. Feel free to check it out :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your case was different then my case. when i request a data from the server in js it always takes time to get it since js is asynchronous. so the problem might be this asynchronous problem but there is a weird issue when i put a then after getting information from the server, that means i am waiting to get an answer and after that I change the state which does not change it.

Comment: @TalTalmon actually my case can be very similar than yours. The thing is that you will never have the latest state updates right after you call `setState({ ... })`. This is why you need a callback (just like in my example) in case you need access state's latest changes. I changed my example with an async operation (just like your case) so you can see it by yourself :)

Comment: the state does not change. forget about the console.log. if the state would change eventually i would see it in the listview, hence it is not change. thanks anyway for your effort to help

Answer (score 1):

Try to initiate your state with empty list like this:

```
this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
});

this.state = { 
    dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows([]),
    isLoading: true
};
```

Note the empty `[]` inside the `cloneWithRows` function.

Then, create a new array and when you fetch the data push it to the new array and update the state with `Object.assign` method.
Something like this:

```
fetchGroups() {
    var dataObject = []

    firebase.database().ref('groups/numbers').once("value", (snap) => {
        snap.forEach((snapshot) => {
            firebase.database().ref('groups/' + snapshot.val()).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                getparticipant = snapshot.val().participant;
                var instantSpace;
                switch (true) {
                    case (getparticipant <= 3):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceOne
                        break;
                    case (getparticipant <= 10):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceTwo
                        break;
                    case (getparticipant <= 20):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceThree
                        break;
                    case (getparticipant > 20):
                        instantSpace= snapshot.val().spaceFourth
                        break;
                }

                dataObject.push({
                    title: snapshot.val().type + ' ' + snapshot.val().brand,
                    groupId: snapshot.val().groupID,
                    description: snapshot.val().model,
                    icon: snapshot.val().icon,
                    partners: snapshot.val().participant,
                    finalDate: snapshot.val().timeMerge,
                    price: instantPrice,
                    photo: snapshot.val().adminPhoto
                });

                // Update the state
                this.setState({ 
                   dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(Object.assign({}, dataObject)) 
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```